# DocuSign Hashing Signed PDF Documents always produces different hash value

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently trying to hash all of the Documents of a completed Envelope. I'm running into an issue where whenever I make a REST call to GET Document it is returning a digitally unique PDF. I've gone about stripping the PDF's metadata and watermark, but cannot deterministically calculate a PDFs SHA256 hash. I've included my short code snippet below. I'm wondering if DocuSign is prepending some unique header data that is changing the hash of my PDF. Any assistance would be very much appreciated. I've also included a txt file that logs the index of the EOF delimiter that represents the actual PDF data that should be static on each call to get a document.

What is confusing me is that I'm able to deterministically retrieve the index of the first EOF delimiter which represents the end of the actual PDF (excludes metatdata & watermark). When I go ahead and hash that sliced buffer it continues to produce a different hash value which leads me to believe that the first `0 -> n` bytes being returned from the get document call to DocuSign are different on subsequent calls.

Code:

```
exports.getDocuments = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Iterate through the list of documents provided and the result of this operation will be a collection [{url: '', data: '', hash: ''}, ...]
    let results = await Promise.all(req.body.docs.map(async (currDoc) => {
      const config = {headers: {'Authorization': req.body.headers.Authorization}}

      // Retrieve Document from DocuSign
      let documentResults = await axios.get(currDoc.config.url, config)
      // Get the Document Buffer up to the first EOF delimeter
      let documentBuffer = await getDocument(documentResults.data, 'binary', currDoc.config.url)

      return {
        url: currDoc.config.url,
        hash: crypto.createHash('sha256').update(documentBuffer).digest('hex') // TODO: Right now always different!!!
      }
    }))

    res.status(200).send(results)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).send(error.message)
  }
}

function getDocument (data, dataType, url) {
  const documentBuffer = Buffer.from(data, dataType)
  const documentId = url.split('/').reverse()[0]
  const eofBuffer = Buffer.from('\n%%EOF', 'ascii')
  const documentEofBufferIdx = getAllIndexes(documentBuffer, eofBuffer)

  console.log(`DocumentID Buffer first index of id=${documentId}: ${documentEofBufferIdx[0]}`)
  console.log('All eof indexes found', documentEofBufferIdx)

  // We want to return the document up to the first EOF, EOFs 2 & 3 refer to the metadata and DocuSign watermark.
  return Promise.resolve(documentBuffer.slice(0, documentEofBufferIdx[0]))
}

// Iterate through the file and collect all of the EOF indexes.
function getAllIndexes (buf, eofBuf) {
  const indexes = []
  let i = -1
  while ((i = buf.indexOf(eofBuf, i + 1)) !== -1) {
    indexes.push(i + eofBuf.length)
  }
  return indexes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you download a document from DocuSign, DocuSign digitally signs it at the time you retrieve the document. A standard X.509 digital signature is used.

If you open the PDF in Adobe PDF reader, it will show the digital sig. The signature includes the datetime it was signed, that's probably the variation you're seeing.

If you understand PDF format, you may be able to pull out the document from the PDF without the DocuSign digital signature. That will not change once the envelope has reached the "completed" status.

What is your use case?

Comment: Thanks for the response. We've identified what is causing the hash to change with help from an engineer at DocuSign. When retrieving a document via call to REST API, the PDFs 'CreationDate' & 'ModDate' change on subsequent requests. However, when downloading the Document directly from the DocuSign Web UI, this is not the case and you are able to deterministically calculate the Document's hash after stripping the metadata and digital signature.